# HTML JAVASCRIPT: add random value to element quantity in a form

Tags: javascript, html, random

I'm a beginner in web development and I am making a bookstore website . Every book has an amount property between 1-5 (which means that if you want to buy a book you can buy the same book 1-5 times) and I have made a button that when you click it , it has to assign random values to the amount properties of each product . I have to perform this task using javascript which I am a complete beginner at . I have written some code but it doesn't work when I click the button as the amount values do not change . I would appreciate your guidance with solving the specific issue . Thank you in advance . 
My code :

```js
//function that has to assign random values to amount properties
function randomfunc() {    
    for(var i=0;i<2;i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("amount")[i].value=Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1;
    }
}
```

```html
  <div id="p-float">


     <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\subtle.jpg" alt = subtle_art/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Subtle Art of not giving an F</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" name = "num"  value = "amount " min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" name = "box" value = "Buy me"/> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div>
      

      <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\work.jpg" alt = deepw/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Deep </br>Work </div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" name = "num"  value = "amount " min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" name = "box" value = "Buy me"/> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div>



  </div>
  
    <button class = "randbtn" onclick="randomfunc()"> Select random products </button>
```

Comment: It should be getElementsByClassName not getElementsByClass.

Comment: The result was the same but thank you for your correction

Comment: You are trying to set the `value` of a DIV. Here is the HTML `<div class="amount">` and here you try to set the value `document.getElementsByClassName("amount")[i].value=`.  DIVs are not inputs and do not have any "value".

Comment: I told you I am a beginner and I need your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you have amount class on outer div so even if you use `getElementsByClassName` that's not going to work.

Working example:

```js
function randomfunc() {
 var list = document.querySelectorAll('.amount');
 for (var n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {
  list[n].value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="p-float">
   <div class="p-float">
      <div class="p-float-in">
         <center>
            <img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\subtle.jpg" alt = subtle_art/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Subtle Art of not giving an F</div>
            <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
            <div > Amount:<input class = "amount" type = "number" name = "num" min = "1" max = "5"/> </div>
            <br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" name = "box" value = "Buy me"/> Buy Me  </div>
         </center>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="p-float">
      <div class="p-float-in">
         <center>
            <img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\work.jpg" alt = deepw/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Deep </br>Work </div>
            <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
            <div> Amount:<input class = "amount" type = "number" name = "num" min = "1" max = "5"/> </div>
            <br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" name = "box" value = "Buy me"/> Buy Me  </div>
         </center>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<button class = "randbtn" onclick="randomfunc()"> Select random products </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **getElementsByClassName** instead of **getElementsByClass** (because js has no getElementsByClass method)

Comment: The result was the same